# Find Context Free Grammar for the following

Tags: context-free-grammar

```
L = {a^n b^m c^k | n=m+2k }
L = {wE(a,b)*|Na(w)+2Nb(w) != Nc(w)}
```

Find Context free grammar for the following(production rules)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, rewrite this as L = {a^2k a^m b^m c^k}. Notice that we can build strings from the outside in by first requiring that two a get added for every c, and then by requiring an additional a get added for every b.

```
S -> aaSc | T    // add two a to the front and one c to the back
T -> aTb | e     // add one a and one b to the middle
```

For the second one, rewrite this as the union of different cases:

1. Na(w) + 2Nb(w) < Nc(w)
2. Na(w) + 2Nb(w) > Nc(w)

We can start with a grammar where Na(w) + 2Nb(w) = Nc(w):

```
S -> Sac | Sca | aSc | acS | caS | cSa | SS | T
T -> Tbcc | Tcbc | Tccb | TScc | bcTc | bccT | cTbc 
          | cTcb | cbTc | cbcT | ccTb | ccbT | TT | e
```

For case 1, we need more c. We can change the above grammar as follows:

```
S -> Sac | Sca | aSc | acS | caS | cSa | SS | T
T -> Tbcc | Tcbc | Tccb | bTcc | bcTc | bccT | cTbc 
          | cTcb | cbTc | cbcT | ccTb | ccbT | TT | C
C -> cC | c
```

That ensures at least one more c gets added somewhere and allows any number of extra c to get added anywhere. For case 2, we need more a or b. We can change the above grammar as follows:

```
S -> Sac | Sca | aSc | acS | caS | cSa | SS | T
T -> Tbcc | Tcbc | Tccb | bTcc | bcTc | bccT | cTbc 
          | cTcb | cbTc | cbcT | ccTb | ccbT | TT | C
C -> aC | bC | a | b
```

That ensures at least one more a or b gets added somewhere and allows any number of extra a or b to get added anywhere.